# Workflow for embedded view

Tags: docusignapi

I'd like to have an email sent to a secondary recipient so they can sign once the first recipient has signed. How would I implement this? Here's what I have

```
signer.Tabs = new Tabs();
        signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();
        var signHere = new SignHere();
        signHere.DocumentId = "1";
        signHere.PageNumber = "1";
        signHere.RecipientId = "1";
        signHere.AnchorUnits = "pixels";
        signHere.AnchorXOffset = "150";
        signHere.AnchorYOffset = "5";

        signHere.AnchorString = "PARTICIPANT SIGNS";
        signHere.Optional = "true";
        signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere);
        envDef.Recipients = new Recipients();
        envDef.Recipients.Signers = new List<Signer>();
        envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer);
        EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);



        var viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest()
        {
            //ReturnUrl = "https://"
            ReturnUrl = "https://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
            ClientUserId = clientId,  // must match clientUserId set in step #2! 
            AuthenticationMethod = "email",
            UserName = user.FullName,
            Email = user.Email
        };
```

The user object above is just a custom class with user information from our system. If I just add another signed with a higher clientuserid will that automatically send the email to that user after the first has signed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the clientUserId means the recipient is considered as an [embedded recipient](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign). No emails will be sent an embedded recipient.

For your use-case add another recipient without the clientUserId and a higher routing order. The second recipient will automatically receive an email after the first recipient finishes signing.

Note: Use different anchor strings for each recipient.

```
   public void CreateEnvelopeWithTwoRecipients()
    {
        string accountID = Init(); //Initialization Code

        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\Agreement.pdf");
        var envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition()
        {
            EmailSubject = "My Envelope Subject",
            Status = "sent",
            Documents = new List<Document>()
            {
                new Document()
                {
                    DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes),
                    Name = "Contract",
                    DocumentId = "1"
                }
            },
            Recipients = new Recipients()
            {
                Signers = new List<Signer>() 
                {
                    new Signer()
                    {
                        Email = "janedoe@acme.com",
                        Name = "Jane Doe",
                        RecipientId = "1",
                        RoutingOrder = "1",
                        clientUserId = "10000"
                        Tabs = new Tabs()
                        {
                            SignHereTabs =  new List<SignHere>()
                            {
                                new SignHere()
                                {
                                    DocumentId = "1",
                                    AnchorXOffset = "150",
                                    AnchorXOffset = "5",
                                    AnchorString = "PARTICIPANT SIGNS",
                                    AnchorUnits = "pixels",
                                    Optional = "true"

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Signer()
                    {
                        Email = "johnsmith@acme.com",
                        Name = "john smith",
                        RecipientId = "2",
                        RoutingOrder = "2",
                        Tabs = new Tabs()
                        {
                            SignHereTabs =  new List<SignHere>()
                            {
                                new SignHere()
                                {
                                    DocumentId = "1",
                                    AnchorXOffset = "150",
                                    AnchorXOffset = "5",
                                    AnchorString = "Second PARTICIPANT SIGNS",
                                    AnchorUnits = "pixels",
                                    Optional = "true"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
        EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountID, envDef);
    }
```